# Xpath syntax to extract node

Tags: xpath

I have this little example:

```
/*
<elements id_srv=1233 id_elem=23>
    <element value1=54 value2=33 value3=62 />
    <element value1=67 value2=14 value3=98 />
    <element value1=21 value2=45 value3=81 />
</elements>
<elements id_srv=1233 id_elem=37>
    <element value1=79 value2=41 value3=80 />
    <element value1=43 value2=17 value3=91 />
    <element value1=29 value2=85 value3=12 />
</elements>
*/

elements.push({id_srv:1233; id_elem:23});
elements.push({id_srv:1233; id_elem:37});

for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
    var node = xmlDoc.xpath('//elements[@id_srv='+elements[i].id_srv+';@id_elem='+elements[i].id_elem+'/element');
    for (var j=0;j<node.length;j++) {
       var value1=elements_group.getElementByName("element").getAttribute("value1");
       var value2=elements_group.getElementByName("element").getAttribute("value2");
       var value3=elements_group.getElementByName("element").getAttribute("value3");
       [...doing whatever with attributes values...]
    }
}
```

where I am trying to extract a node and its childs as represented in the commented part finding it by its attributes using xpath so then I can process child's attributes.... My doubt is xpath syntax since I get nothing... is that xpath syntax right?

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Cheers, 
Luigi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to match on the `id_src` **and** `id_elem` attributes, I think you want something like this

```
xmlDoc.xpath("//elements[@id_src='" + elements[i].id_src +
    "' and @id_elem='" + elements[i].id_elem + "']/element")
```

Comment: Hi Phil, I used var path = "//elements[id_srv='"+elements[i].id_src+"' and @id_elem='"+elements[i].id_elem+"']"; var node = xmlDoc.evaluate(path, xmlDoc, null, 9, null); because in Javascript I can't call directly xpath but I still get "undefined" even if in xmlDoc there is a xml document containing different <elements></elements> nodes... what could be?...

Comment: or at least, is there a way to get node with its childs filtering by its node attributes and without using xpath?...

Comment: Nevermind... figured it out as you suggested doing a getElementByXpath function which evaluates the path...